# biblatex-chicago with authordate style is not showing page numbers in citations

Tags: biblatex-chicago

As far as I'm aware, Chicago style requires that page numbers be included in bracketed citations where available, for example (Name 2020, 15-17).

I am using `\autocite{test}` on a resource that looks like:

```
@book{test,
  title={Book Title},
  author={Name},
  date={2020},
  pages={15-17}
}
```

but the ouput of the autocite is (Name 2020), without the page numbers.

The [specification](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/examples/cms-dates-intro.pdf) for the biblatex-chicago authordate citation format gives usage examples including page numbers as I described, but I am not getting them for some reason. Am I missing something?

TIA

Comment: I would have thought that normally with a book, you wouldn't include the pages in the bib entry and instead include them in the citation: `\autocite[15-17]{test}`.

Comment: @DavidPurton That's it, that's what I was missing! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Although some entry types make use of the `pages` field (e.g., `@article`, `@inbook`, `@incollection`, etc.) it wouldn't be usual to include a `pages` field for `@book`. And `biblatex-chicago` never prints the `pages` field in citations with its author date style, only in the bibliography.

Instead you should put the pages in the citation `postnote` like this:

```
\autocite[15-17]{test}
```

This will give:

> (Name 2020, 15–17)

You can also use the `prenote` argument for `\autocite`:

```
\autocite[See][15-17]{test}
```

which gives:

> (See Name 2020, 15–17)